# On the product of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables which take only the values $0$ and $1$ with identical positive probabilities. Can $X$ and $Y$ be chosen such that $P(XY=0)=1$?

My attempt:

Let $P(X=0)=P(Y=0)=p$.

Then,$P(XY=0)=2p-p^2$.

Therefore $P(XY=0)=1 \Rightarrow p=1$.

Therefore not possible as $1-p=0$.

Comment: Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy By identical probabilities I mean X and Y have identical distribution

Comment: @Laufen I have edited.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X,Y$ have the same Bernoulli distribution, we can write $P(X=0)=P(Y=0)=p_1$ and $P(X=1)=P(Y=1)=p_2$ where $p_1,p_2\in[0,1]$.

Now, the probability $P(XY=0)=1-P(X\ne0 , Y\ne 0)=1-P(X=1,Y=1)$.

And since $X,Y$ are independent, $P(X=1,Y=1)=P(X=1)P(Y=1)=p_2^2$.

So, yes, $X,Y$ can be chosen such that $P(XY=0)=1$, by choosing $p_2=0$.

Comment: So it cannot be done if the probabilities are positive right?

Comment: @smbch If $p_2$ is positive then no